# Marketing Cloud: Data Extension setup

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I am running 3 different Journeys in Marketing Cloud based on different segments of our contact list in Salesforce. Is it better to create one Data Extension that basically contains all of my SF Contacts, and then set filters on the entry event into the Journey to grab the specific contacts I want? Or should I have a different Data Extension for each Journey that each updates separately?

I'm trying to understand the pros and cons of this but I'm having difficulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither way is wrong, but I go with having an 'audience' DE for each journey to help keep things clean.

1. Bring down all your data from SF into a single contacts DE.
2. Use queries or data filters to apply the criteria needed, going from the contacts DE to each Journey Audience DE as append.
3. Use the entry event criteria 'subscriber key is not null' or 'email address is not null' on each journey audience DE.  It will just pick up net new subscribers.

As long as you are comfortable with your entry criteria being in SQL, this approach tends to be the cleanest, as now you have a single place for each journey to update contact data, filter, and report.